# Slow Magento Homepage

Tags: performance, magento, magento-1.7

Hello is there any direct or simple reason to `Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien::start` take 15 seconds to load?

I have in the same server other project and other PHP framework and this is only happening to one site.

This is what I am having, what does **blocking** mean?

[image: Log]

Comment: It depends on you used cache backend. Are you using 'files'?

Comment: I know I am using files....

Comment: I notice that another site of mine just did the same: a Joomla with JSession::_start

Comment: Does deleting /var/session make a temporary improvement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bad server vhost configuration. It was not allowing the server to use Fast CGI. Nothing to do with Magento.